# Pourquoi Mme de Sévigné vouvoyait sa fille ?

Tags: histoire, vouvoiement

Je suis en train de lire les [lettres](https://resources.warburg.sas.ac.uk/pdf/ebh694b2456422.pdf) de Mme de Sévigné et j'ai été un peu étonné de constater qu'elle vouvoyait constamment sa fille, Mme de Grignan. À titre d'exemple :

> (29 janvier 1674) Ma bonne, je suis en colère contre vous. Comment !
> vous  avez la cruauté de me dire, connaissant mon cœur comme vous
> faites, que vous m’incommoderez chez moi, que vous m’ôterez  mes
> chambres, que vous me romprez la tête ! Allez ! vous devriez être
> honteuse de me dire de ces sortes de verbiages.
>
> (29 mai 1675) Comment voulez-vous que je ne pleure pas, ma très chère
> bonne, en lisant votre lettre ? Il ne m’en faut pas tant pour  fondre
> ! Au nom de Dieu, ma bonne, ne vous amusez point à  retourner sur des
> riens.
>
> (20 octobre 1679) Quoi ! vous pensez m’écrire de grandes lettres, sans
> me  dire un mot de votre santé ; je pense, ma pauvre bonne, que  vous
> vous moquez de moi.

S'agit-il d'une procédure de style ou plutôt d'une coutume de l'époque ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'était une coutume, tout à fait normale dans la haute société à l'époque de Madame de Sévigné, que de se vouvoyer entre parents et enfants et aussi entre époux. Même de vouvoyer les enfants encore jeunes, du moins en public, les parents avaient des nurses qui s'occupaient des enfants et ne les voyaient en général qu'en public.

> Au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, sous l’influence de la préciosité et des multiples ouvrages de civilité qui ont fleuri depuis le début du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle, le vous de déférence est de rigueur envers les personnes de haut rang mais également dans les conversations intimes (Mme de Sévigné dans ses *Lettres* ne déroge jamais à cette règle, malgré toute l’affection qu’elle porte à sa fille)<sup>1</sup>.

Je pense que le vouvoiement des enfants doit être très rare de nos jours. Le vouvoiement des parents par les enfants et entre époux est devenu plus rare mais subsiste dans certains milieux.

Deux article qu'on pourra lire sur le sujet : dans *Le Monde* : [Les anciens continuent d'apprécier le vouvoiement](https://www.lemonde.fr/vous/article/2005/05/27/les-anciens-continuent-d-apprecier-le-vouvoiement_654874_3238.html) (2005), dans *Le Figaro* [Le vouvoiement, un usage menacé d'extinction](https://www.lefigaro.fr/actualite/2007/05/21/01001-20070521ARTFIG90137-le_vouvoiement_un_usage_menace_d_extinction.php) (2007). Cet article du Figaro cite un cas de famille où les parents vouvoient les enfants.

> C'est le cas chez (...) « Pour leur apprendre à être responsables », monsieur vouvoie les enfants. Madame les tutoie après les avoir vouvoyés : « Quand ils sont nés, leur apparition était presque divine, alors je les ai vouvoyés. Puis je les ai tutoyés pour leur faire plaisir quand ils ont eu le bac ! » La progéniture, quant à elle, tutoie les parents !

Extrait de *Le tu et le vous. L'art français de compliquer les choses* (Étienne Kern, Flammarion, 2020) :

> Être vouvoyé par son propre père ? Voilà ce que le héros de *Mon père avait raison*<sup>2</sup>, de Sacha Guitry, ne semble pas prêt à accepter. Pour la plupart d'entre nous, il en irait de même, bien sûr : entre parents et enfants, on se tutoie, ...

([En lire plus](https://books.google.fr/books?id=UFn9DwAAQBAJ&pg=PP23&dq=sacha%20guitry%20mon%20p%C3%A8re%20avait%20raison%20tutoiement&hl=fr&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy9Ovw9Oj0AhVeA2MBHW4-AiIQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=sacha%20guitry%20mon%20p%C3%A8re%20avait%20raison%20tutoiement&f=false))

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> : Lauriane Mouraret.  [*Interlocution et style tragique à l’âge classique :  Théophile de Viau, Rotrou,Corneille et Racine*](http://www.theses.fr/2020GRALL030).   Littératures.   Université Grenoble Alpes (Thèse de doctorat, 2020).

<sup>2</sup> : Cette pièce de Sacha Guitry est parue en 1919.</sup>

Comment: In the 1970s, I worked at an NGO based in Paris. I am American. I had two French colleagues who, to my surprise, used "vous" when talking to their mothers. The first time I heard it (overheard a phone conversation), I was stunned. Both women had "noms a particule".

Comment: @Arlo Thanks for this feedback. This can still be the case in some families as the *Figaro* article reports. I know it's difficult on a qwerty keyboard but we're particular about properly accentuated letters on French letters since many people come here to check/improve their French. It's *nom **à** particule*. Never seen you around, 1st time on FL? Hope to see you back.

Answer (score -1):

Si, si, les arguments avancés jouent certainement comme il semble que les époux de feu le président de république, GiRAC, se vouvoyaient.  Mes remarques: Par le vouvoyement on crée, à dessein, une certaine distance personelle, donc si les parents vouvoyent leurs enfants dès un certain âge de maturité, disons à partir de 18 ans, ils veulent les responsabiliser pour la vie imminente d'adultes en leur signalant que la période de jeunesse est en passe finale et que, partant, ils ne devraient plus tant compter sur une aide massive (financère) des parents. D'autre part, cela signifie aussi que les parents soi-mêmes, ils voudraient être vouvoyés. Troisièment: les peuples d'extraction latine quoiqu'individualistes à outrance ont l'habitude de vivre en des tribus, donc le ''vous'' montre leur appartenance à un clan bien défini, donc le mari ne voit dans la femme  vouvoyée pas l'individu mais un membre bien aimée de ladite tribu > genre, et vous-là bas qu'en pensez-vous? 4) Pour un anglophone il est certes très difficle d'interprêter la nuance sur le moment quand on ne connaît pas toute l'étendue du vocabu-laire de choix. Parfois, il s'agit aussi de moquerie, d'ironie ou  d'hypocrisie pour obtenir une faveur hors du commun. 5) On recherche la distance pour avoir sa paix intérieure > faire intentionellement perdre l'envie à l'autre de nous rendre visite > Je ne désire pas devenir > être ton copain. ''Tu'' n'es pas assez attractif > attrayante pour être fréquentable. Notons que les pays type germaniques ont toute autre approche joviale envers la question , tels la Suède et la Suisse a-lémanique! // La France a gardé, n'empêche la Révolution de 1789, une allure monarchique, rien qu'à voir le présent genre de gouvernement de dès 1958 de monarche - président intouchable - immunité totale pendant 5, 10 voire 15 ans de son règne absolu comparable à celui du Vatican. Si

Comment: (continuation)......Si qn. vous tutoye, c'est qu'il/elle cherche plus de proximité personnelle qu'il vous serait agréable, vous considère, dans le bon  comme mauvais sens, comme son pair, son compère, complice, allié de (future) rencontre. Ah, le champ de raisonnement est vaste et calculé aussi dans celui de la parenté: Avec certaines gens on ne voudrait jamais être à tu et à toi. // Un père de 10 enfants peut avoir perdu avoir envie de fréquenter tous les enfants, n'a plus la force de s'occuper davantage de tout ce beau monde, en est las un peu, donc, vive la distance du ''vous, vous, vous''